# How to configure Redis in Google Cloud Platform connected to App Engine to autoscale

Tags: redis, google-cloud-platform

I want to deploy a **autoscalable** `Redis` in `GCP` and connect it to my **app** in app engine in my `app.yml`

Is Cloud Launcher the proper way to launch the Redis Service? I did so and selected the `Redis` *click to deploy* option (Not the bitnami one).

I configured the instances and deployed them.

After the instances were ready, the next command appeared:

```
gcloud compute ssh --project <project-name> --zone <zone-name> <redis-instance-name>
```

After having this, do I have to configure the next things?

- Instance IP address (I want it to be only accessible from inside my GCP Account) (Do I need to configure the 3 instances or does the sentinel takes care of the redirection?)
- Password of the sentinel redis
- Firewall

Comment: did you find the answer?